# Google place picker is not launching on Android Mi phones

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-places-api, android-location

I am facing a problem with Google Place Picker in Android Redmi Phones version 5.1.1. I am using the following code for launching the Google Place Picker.

```
try {
       PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                    startActivityForResult(builder.build(SelectLocationActivity.this), 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(SelectLocationActivity.this,""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I have added following permissions and api key and google play service version.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<application>
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="my-api-key" />
</application>
```

It is working on Every phone except Android Redmi Note2. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please state the version of google play services of the device. Any exception thrown? Is google play services present on the device? Check if the play services is available, because due to Chinese legislation they are shipped without Play Services    https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context) You have to start resolution if the play services are not present.

Comment: What error you are receiving ?

Comment: No errors. Just the activity starts and immediately closes. No errors are appearing in error logcat @AndroidHacker

Comment: @Kaushal28 are you using proguard/obfuscation for your app?

Comment: I even dont know about this. @Vektor88

Comment: I think that he is running in debug mode, so is very unlikely that proguard is used. Did you try to see if `GooglePlayServices` are available?

Comment: How to exactly check it? Because all other Google apps (maps, play store, chrome, play games) are working on the device.

Comment: @Kaushal28 try running `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)` and comparing the result against `ConnectionResult.SUCCESS`.

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Comment: @activesince93 Yes! now Red mi note 3 has Android 6.0 and may be this bug is fixed. So ask run time permission and you can launch the placepicker activity. (I'm commenting  because I've started bounty on this question and got the solution).

Comment: @Kaushal28 I don;t think to open PlacePicker via `intent` we require any kind of permission. And btw I have already given the location permission and still it is crashing. I am using `Redmi Note 4` with `6.0`.

Comment: @activesince93 Yes you don't need any permission for opening it using intent, but what I assumed was that after opening the activity, due to some permission bugs (in SDK 5.1.1 with no runtime permissions) it was crashing even after giving permission explicitly. But after Marsh mellow update, my code started working without any changes.

Comment: We are facing similar issue with Mi 4 and Android 6.0. Only difference is that instead of closing, it gives error, "Unfortunately, Google Play Server...". It's important to note that Place picker is working fine in all other phones except this one so that permission or key is for sure not an issue.

Comment: @yumoji : I am also facing the exact same issue.

Comment: @V33R please inform if you find any solution.

Comment: After the update of Android 7.0 in Redmi Note 4, the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your manifest file, I believe that you added the key inside of `manifest` tag and not `application`. Based on Android docs, the key should be added like this:

```
<application>
...
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot test it with the device you mentioned, but I remember that I a similar issue with a `Samsung` device (the code was working on every device, except that one). Also, check the logs again, maybe there is a message and you missed it.

Comment: First of all you are right about key placing. But this question is not asked by me so can't edit. I've placed my key correctly as you mentioned. But if the key was placed wrongly, than it should not work on any device. But this is working perfectly fine in all other devices (I've tested on emulator also and it is working.) Also I've faced this same(key placed wrongly) issue at the beginning when I started building my app. If this is the case, Place picker activity should open but should not display location suggestions or auto suggestions etc. BTW thanks for giving your time :)

Comment: make sure your Redmi Phones have GoogleServices installed.

Comment: @ohdroid how to exactly check it?

Comment: If the device has play store, it has play services. If the device has successfully ran google maps, it has play services. And in any case, you can search "google play services" in the play store.

Comment: Then yes it has Google play services @ohdroid

Answer (score -1):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp" >
  ...
  <uses-permission
```

android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
      ...

Add this code to your activity in OnCreate

```
 askForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,LOCATION);
```

///call this method

```
 private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {

                //This is called if user has denied the permission before
                //In this case I am just asking the permission again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've already added this code in my app. FYI: Default android version of Red Mi note 3 is 5.1 Lollipop. And my code works for 6.0 or above perfectly fine in other phones. So no runtime permissions are required for this particular phone. Please do research before answering the questions :)